# How to initialize 2d array to contain images?

Tags: php, arrays

```
int[][] myArray = {
                     {236, 189, 189, 0}, 
                     {236,  80, 189, 189}, 
                     {236, 0, 189, 80}, 
                     {236, 189, 189,  80}
                  };
```

so, instead of these numbers, I wanted to initialize it with the following images:

1. jpeg
2. jpeg.... etc

By the way, I'm trying to display the tiles for my 2d game in php.

Comment: Do you want to store the names of the images or just the images? Because you just can store images in an array....

Answer (score 0):

First off all the code in the blockquote isn't PHP in PHP you create an array like this:

> `$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");`

And to solve your problem just create an Array with your filenames in it.

```
$tileMap = array(array("1.jpeg","2.jpeg"),array("3.jpeg","4.jpeg"));
```